# Cutting all polygons with each other - mega slicing

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-processing

Draw a big circle.  Then a smaller one on top and then a smaller one and a smaller one.

You see a stack of circles like a bullseye.  If you had drawn these in QGIS the other way you would only see the largest one as it hides the others.

Is there a way in a single layer to slice every feature with every other?

Basically, I have contours and I only want the band between each polygon rather than the stack of progressively bigger polys like the bullseye example.

I have perfect data where all polygons are closed and sit perfectly inside each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the contours are line feature class and are **closed contour lines**, as you can see below:

[image]

then you need to use `lines to polygons` tool from `Processing toolbox -> QGIS geoalgorithoms -> Vector geometry tools -> lines to polygons`

It will give you the following output, which is topologically not correct (Overlapping each other):

[image]

To modify the above topology, you need to use GRASS -> v.clean as @Klewis suggested from `Processing toolbox -> GRASS GIS 7 commands -> Vector -> v.clean`, and in cleaning tool use `Break`, as you can see below:

[image]

The output result is now topologically correct:

[image]

I selected a polygon in the above image to show you that it is a valid topology.

If the contours are already polygons in separate shapefiles, you can use `difference` tool repeatedly to get the difference between big polygons and smaller polygons and finally use `Merge` tool to put them in one polygon shapefile.

Comment: This is the best solution. Breaks up the polygons as expected and maintains attribution. Thanks

Comment: v.clean consistently fails when used in QGIS on Windows 7. GDAL contour with -p works perfectly for small datasets, but can run for days on large files. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The geometric operation you're looking for is called 'union' in most software. In e.g.  QGIS, the tool is under Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools. [You can read about geometric operations here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_overlay_tools.html?highlight=union), for starters.

After unioning you'll have to do some work to reconcile the attribute data, but any advice about that process should go in a separate question, if you get stuck.