# Nested polygons in QGIS overlap and don't show the real colour gradient

Tags: qgis, polygon, color

I am working with nested polygons in QGIS and each of them has got a specific let's say `n` (numeric) value represented with a given colour gradient.

- All my polygons are loaded into one shapefile
- If I use `Feature blending mode` = `Normal` I miss (don't know why) some of the nested polygons, but colours are ok, see below:

  [image]
- If I use `Feature blending mode` = `Multiply` QGIS shows me ALL the polygons BUT for all of them their colours overlap and their areas become darker than the reality, see below:

  [image]

What I need is to show ALL my polygons with their real (not-overlapped) colour gradient.

Is there a way I can get around this?

Comment: If you want to show all polygons, then you need to correct the topology. Having overlapping polygons in one shapefile is actually a topological error.

Comment: How can I correct the topology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To modify the above topology, you need to use GRASS -> v.clean from `Processing toolbox -> GRASS GIS 7 commands -> Vector -> v.clean`, and in cleaning tool use `Break`, as you can see below:

[image]

You may need to re-enter the values in attribute table after cleaning your polygon shapefile.

You can refer to my answer to the question: [Cutting all polygons with each other - mega slicing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243808/cutting-all-polygons-with-each-other-mega-slicing) for illustrations.

Comment: Hi, your suggestion worked. But how can I remove the duplicated polygons created with the v.clean function so that I can only keep the 'real' ones? Is the 'rmdupl' function? (should I reopen my question?) Thanks

Comment: You need to ask a new question for this. But I suggest to try 'rmdupl' function. It may solve the problem.

Comment: new question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258177/topology-in-qgis-shapefile-grass-and-v-clean-nested-polygons

Answer (score 4):

If the polygons are overlapping and you want to keep it this way (because that's what it should look like or you dont want to bother to fix it) you could try tu use the "Control feature rendering order" in the Layer Styling dialog

[image]

You may choose to order by area to get smaller polygon on top of larger polygon. This will work well in case of totally nested polygon, if it's partial overlap of several of polygon it could be impossible to display all polygon.