# Topology in QGIS shapefile, GRASS and v.clean (nested polygons)

Tags: qgis, polygon, grass-gis

Following this: [Nested polygons in QGIS overlap and don't show the real colour gradient](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257687/nested-polygons-in-qgis-overlap-and-dont-show-the-real-colour-gradient)

I applied the GRASS function `v.clean -> break` as suggested by @ahmadhanb and the shapefile now shows correctly all the nested basins without using the `Feature blending mode = Multiply`.

However I noticed that in the attribute table the `v.clean` function created ~2 times more variables than the original shapefile (e.g. original shapefile 250 polygons, after v.clean 500 polygons). There are then duplicated polygons that eventually create issues when doing a Join.

How can I remove the duplicated polygons created by `v.clean` and keep ONLY the 'good' ones that appear in the QGIS environment when selected?

I tried to apply `rmdupl` within `v.clean` but the shapefile did not change at all!

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution instead of `rmdupl` within `v.clean` is to use `Delete duplicate geometries` from `QGIS Toolbox -> QGIS geoalgorithms -> Vector general tools -> Delete duplicate geometries`.

I tested on the following polygon shapefile that has duplicate polygons:

[image]

I used Delete duplicate geometries tool

[image]

The result is a shapefile without duplicate polygons.

[image]