# Overlapping polygons layer order

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon

Is there a way in QGIS to prioritize the layering order overlapping polygons. I have a shapefile with numbers in the attribute table from 1-20. Each number is associated with its own polygon. I want to layer the polygons from highest number to lowest. I would like to colour fill them as well. And it's basically a contour map.

Comment: Maybe related topic: [How to change feature draw order in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183048/how-to-change-feature-draw-order-in-qgis)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option to activate the `Control feature rendering order` under Symbology:

[image]

in which you can identify the rendering order based on a field:

[image]

However, since overlapping polygons are considered topologically incorrect, it is better to clean the contour polygon to get rid of overlappings. The solution is to use v.clean tool from `Processing toolbox -> GRASS GIS 7 commands -> Vector -> v.clean`, and in cleaning tool use `Break`. Please have a look at [Cutting all polygons with each other - mega slicing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/243888/63384) answer which solve this issue with illustrations.

Comment: Thank you for a tip about `"mega slicing"`

Comment: @Taras You are welcome :)